# Product groups in US that has no sale in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have written the following two queries for the below requirement. Please let me know which method is correct or both methods are wrong? Thanks a lot

There were two tables -

'Orders' with - order_id(PK), item id, quantity, order_date [Transactional Table]

'Catalog' with-item id, product group, location [Dimension Table]

They asked to write a SQL code that will return the product groups of US that has no sale in any unit(i.e all the item id from an individual product group has no sale).

```
1st Method:
with cte as
(
select c.*,o.order_id,
case when o.order_id is not null then 1 else 0 end sale_ind 
from Catalog c
left join Orders o
on c.item_id = o.item_id 
and c.location = 'US'
)
select product_group 
from cte 
group by product_group having sum(sale_ind) = 0
```

```
2nd Method:
select c.* 
from Catalog c 
where c.location='US' 
and item_id not in (
   select item_id 
   from Orders)
```

Comment: why don't you create the tables enter some data and test it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.product_group
FROM Catalog c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o
    on c.item_id = o.item_id
WHERE c.location='US' 
AND o.item_id is null
```

Left join: because you want catalog records (left side) even if there are no order records (right side). The second part of the WHERE clause filters out instances where there are orders.

You can’t use an inner join as that would return only records where the Catalog record had corresponding orders, which is not what you want

Comment: Why a Left Join would be used? And why kept Catalog on left? Can I use inner join between orders and catalogs?

Answer (score 0):

> They asked to write a SQL code that will return the product groups of US that has no sale in any unit(i.e all the item id from an individual product group has no sale).

I would tend to go with `not exists` for this:

```
select distinct c.product_group
from catalog c
where c.location = 'US' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from orders o
                  where o.item_id = c.item_id
                 );
```

That said, both your queries look okay, but the first is correct.  The second is returning all catalog records not all `product_group`s.  As for the second, I would discourage you from ever using `not in` with a subquery.  No rows are returned if `item_id` returned by the subquery is ever `NULL`.